# Can jQuery functionality for selecting id's be used synchronously with selecting classes?

Tags: jquery, syntax, attributes

I have several functions which include a straight forward jQuery syntax to find elements by id. Such as

```
$('#thisId').val() != '';
```

If I had the following code:

```
$('.thisClass').val() != '';
```

For argument's sake, let's assume that the `.thisClass` class is unique. If so, would jQuery work in the same way?

The crux is, I am looking for a way to create a mock second id for inputs.

Comment: that class will work int the same way, but i am unable to understand what you want to do

Comment: Yes, you can work entirely with classes. The same is not true of ids, which must be unique.

Comment: Am I the only one confused as to why you would need a second ID?

Comment: @FDL Well, I had some functionality linked to sequentially labeled ID's, but other functionality forced me to change the ID's etc.  So I thought it might be easiest to just add classes with the same name as the old ID's and then change the ´#´ to a `.`. That was the idea anyway

Comment: Only curious, but what digital _faux pas_ justified the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work the same. Just make sure your class(your second id class) is unique to avoid conflicts. If you need second id, you can use their id as their class as well

```
<input id="test1" class="test1" />
```

Then you can call it like this

```
$('#test1')
$('.test1')
```

OR

Have a custom html attribute

```
 <input id="test1" secondId="test1" />
```

Then you can call it like this

```
$('#test1')
$('[secondId=test1]')
```

Other **jQuery plugins** use this *technique*.
Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

If you're going to use it inside a loop to produce a dynamic ID, the syntax should be something like this:

```
var i = 1;
$("[secondId=test" + i + "]")
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was not aware that I could spontaneously create attributes.  That might be the exact thing I am looking for

Comment: No problem! I've been using a lot of jQuery plugins like KendoUI and DHTMLX. That's where I get those. :)

Comment: if I was to incorporate a for() loop, would the syntax be `('[seondID=test[i]]')` or perhaps `('[seondID=test + i])`?